# How do I remove a duplicate Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

I've got a duplicate account on Facebook, however I have no access to that account.
How can I delete it?

Answer (score 5):

There is a contact form in the help center for this request: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=duplicate_account

Answer (score 2):

Report that account. That's the only way to delete it. But I think they'll delete both of your accounts, because duplicates are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Do you at least have access to the e-mail address tied to the duplicate Facebook account? If you do, you can reset the password and gain access to the account, then delete it yourself. This eliminates the risk of loosing both accounts like genesis suggested, although I'm not sure about that. If you still can't get access, then I'll do as Alexandre suggested and contact Facebook.